# New member gets user account

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, user-account

I would like to have a similar situation to the following.

When a new member registers herself. She will automatically create a new User account for Wordpress. If the user changes the information of this user account (name/mailaddress) this is automatically synced with the information in the CRM.

The user has access to certain elements of the site for as long as they are members.

I also want to use the user accounts to make an integration with Nextcloud so that the users can login there with the same credentials. Contact groups must be synced then.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/) (which provides 2-way sync between WordPress profiles and CiviCRM contact details) and [CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) to achieve this.

Have a look at the docs for CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync to see how you can use the Groups or Members plugin to restrict access to WordPress content for your members.

A simple Membership Contribution page in CiviCRM is all that's required to enable sign-ups - with the added benefit that you *don't* have to enable the WordPress setting that means "Anyone can register".

Answer (score 1):

If by "When a new member registers herself" you mean filling in a CiviMember (ie Contribution) Form - then you should be able to set 'create CMS user' on the Profile that is exposed on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a page in Wordpress that has a CiviCRM Profile embedded in it, like: https://culturalenterprises.org.uk/register-as-a-user/

Update the advanced settings on the profile so that CMS account creation is mandatory, and that it is set to update the details of any matching contact it finds. For this to work your CiviCRM profile must include the field Individual > Email > Primary, or the user account registration option won't work.  I also strongly recommend you enable recaptcha:

[image: Profile Advanced Settings screen]

As for updating details, we again send people to a page with a CiviCRM profile embedded, so they update CiviCRM directly.  We provide links to the Wordpress user editor screen from that page, if they want to update their password or email.

[image: Profile Screen]

No idea what Nextcloud is though :)